# webpage page hangs when execute jquery using selenium

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, selenium

I am trying to find element using jquery in selenium. But Whenever i executes my code it hangs the webpage and after that my script doesn't execute. It gives pop up in the browser displaying message "A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding" always. Please help me why it is happening and how can i execute my jquery using selenium successfully thanks.

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    String findButton = "return $(\".k-link\");";
    List element = (List) js.executeScript(findButton);

    System.out.println("Size of parent = " + element.size());
```

Is there any setting required to execute this code in the browser?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"return $(\".k-link\");"` will return a jquery object you want to return a `DOM` element. You can use the `get` method. The .get() method grants access to the DOM nodes underlying each jQuery object.

```
String findButton = "return $(\".k-link\").get(0);";
List element = (List) js.executeScript(findButton);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i am getting null pointer exception. Element is present and visible in browser but i am able to detect that element only when i place my mouse curser on that element using Robot class. I read jquery or javaScript can detect element even though it is hidden, I tried by both but here it is not detecting. Any help?

Comment: Can you give the webpage you are looking at?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, the link is [link](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/column-resizing). Actually i am looking for element which has class name k-resize-handle to resize the column. problem is that first of all element is not accessible using class name in code. Even though some how i am managing to get it using robot class, i am not able to resize it using drag and drop api or by using robot class methods. Nothing is working to resize the column. It works only when i used both drag and drop and robot class method to press mouse then drag and release mouse.

Comment: Is this problem with widget? Please help me.